# Self teaching Ordinary Differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

I'm currently teaching myself how to do ODE's and I have come across some questions which I'm a bit lost with:

The First:

> $ x \frac {dy} {dx} + 2y = x \sqrt {y^3} $ (for x > 0).

The second I have seen very often on exam papers and am unsure how to go about it:

> The population of fish in a pond is described by the Verhulst equation
>   $$ \frac {dP} {dt} = rP(1 − \frac {P}{K}). $$
>   Initially, the population of fish in the pond is 800 and the carrying capacity of the fish population is K = 2000. After 2 months, the fish population has grown to 1000.
>
> (a) How many fish will be in this pond after 5 months?
>
> (b) After how many months will the fish population be 1300?

Any help for either topic would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first is a Bernoulli equation. Write it as
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}+\frac2xy=y^{3/2}\tag{1}$$
Let $v=y^{1-3/2}=y^{-1/2}$, by Chain Rule we have $$\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac12y^{-3/2}\frac{dy}{dx}$$
So, multiplying $(1)$ by $-\frac12y^{-3/2}$ we get
\begin{align*}
-\frac12y^{-3/2}-\frac1xy^{-1/2}&=-\frac12\\[3pt]
\frac{dv}{dx}-\frac1xv&=-\frac12\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation $(2)$ is linear. An integrating factor for this is $\mu(x)=e^{\int -\frac1xdx}=e^{-\ln x}=x^{-1}$. After multiply eq $(2)$ by $\mu(x)=x^{-1}$ becomes
\begin{align*}
x^{-1}\frac{dv}{dx}-x^{-2}v&=-\frac12x^{-1}\\[3pt]
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left\{x^{-1}v\right\}&=-\frac12x^{-1}
\end{align*}
Integrating both sides give us
$$x^{-1}v=-\frac12\ln x+c\quad\implies\quad v=-\frac12x\ln x+cx$$
Then
$$\boxed{\color{blue}{y=\left(-\tfrac12x\ln x+cx\right)^{-2}}}$$